# How can I show specific texts inside a div by the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a small text translated in 3 languages. I am looking to show the first text in English, and above the text to show two buttons, one that says French and one that says Italian. And I want once you click on French, to display the text in French, and the same with Italian. This means that I will have three separate divs, one for English, one for French and one for Italian. I only want to show one of them on the page, depending on which button I click. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: jQuery has `.show()` and `.hide()` for instance. Do you know how to make a button run code? Have you attempted to solve this yourself in any way?

Comment: @ChrisG is right. But you can also use the `.html()` or `.text()` functions to replace the text in correct language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-lang="en"]').addClass('active');
  $('.flag').on('click', function() {
    $('[data-lang]').removeClass('active');
    $('[data-lang="' + $(this).data('lang') + '"]').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.flag.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.text {
  display: none;
}

.text.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-lang="en" class="flag">English</button>
<button data-lang="fr" class="flag">Français</button>
<button data-lang="it" class="flag">Italiano</button>
<div data-lang="en" class="text">My text in English</div>
<div data-lang="fr" class="text">Mon texte en français</div>
<div data-lang="it" class="text">Il mio testo in italiano</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, it works. But however, when I first load the page it shows all the texts in all the languages. How can I prevent that and at first, when page loads, to only show the text in the first language, that being English? The script is up on www.helion-ms.com

Comment: @naty1982 you need to hide all the `.text` by applying them `display: none;` via CSS

Comment: I just did, with display:none and it was fixed. It works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is create a relation between button and your desired div, and then show the related div only on click and hide the others, in my code you can increase and decrease the div's, no need to touch the jQuery or CSS code, just add or remove div's from HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btnWrapper button').click(function(){
            $('.btnWrapper button').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var realtion = $(this).data('relation');
            $('.translatedText>div').removeClass('active');
            $('.translatedText').find('#' + realtion).addClass('active');
        });
        
    });
```

```css
 .btnWrapper button.active {
            background-color: red;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .translatedText > div {
            display: none;
        }
        .translatedText > div.active {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btnWrapper">
        <button class="active" data-relation="eng">English</button>
        <button data-relation="fre">French</button>
        <button data-relation="ita">Italian</button>
    </div>
    <div class="translatedText">
        <div id="eng" class="active">
            I am English's Div
        </div>
        <div id="fre">
            I am French's Div
        </div>
        <div id="ita">
            I am Italian's Div
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    document.querySelector(".btn-eng").addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.querySelector(".eng").classList.add("active");
        document.querySelector(".french").classList.remove("active");
        document.querySelector(".italian").classList.remove("active");
    });
    document.querySelector(".btn-french").addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.querySelector(".french").classList.add("active");
        document.querySelector(".eng").classList.remove("active");
        document.querySelector(".italian").classList.remove("active");
    });
    document.querySelector(".btn-italian").addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.querySelector(".italian").classList.add("active");
        document.querySelector(".eng").classList.remove("active");
        document.querySelector(".french").classList.remove("active");
    });
```

```css
*{
    font-size: 1rem;
 }
 .container {
              margin: auto;
              height: 100px;
              width: 250px;
 }
 .flex {
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         flex-direction: column;
         height: 100%;
         width: 100%;
 }
 .eng,
 .french,
 .italian {
            display: none;
 }
 .active {
           display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="section">
                <p class="eng active">Hello Developers out there!</p>
                <p class="french">Bonjour les développeurs là-bas!</p>
                <p class="italian">Ciao sviluppatori là fuori!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
                <button class="btn-eng">English</button>
                <button class="btn-french">French</button>
                <button class="btn-italian">Italian</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```